# Dynamically change avatar marker z-index on google map based on position of surrounding markers

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, marker

I might have an interesting challenge for you all. I generate many markers on my Google map API (javascript) including one that represents an avatar that moves around the map.

I set the other icons on the map at a lower z-index than my avatar. It looks good when the avatar is lower than the surrounding markers, but when my avatar moves higher than other markers while touching them, it looks like the avatar is walking over them, instead of just moving past them.

let me show you 2 pics:

good

[image]

bad

[image]

Anyway I could change my avatar's z-index without really hurting the performance of the page?

Thanks a lot Stack, I did research this one and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. But I have no idea how taxing it is.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

    if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markers[i].getPosition(),marker.getPosition()) < 20)
    {

                if (marker.getPosition().lng() > markers[i].getPosition().lng()) {
                    marker.setZIndex(98);                       
                }
                else {
                    marker.setZIndex(100);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

All of my markers are put in the markers array. My character is the variable marker. The function is called every time the character moves vertically.

Hope this can help someone else one day.